# Qual o feminino de “elefante”?

Tags: feminino-masculino

Comumente se diz *elefoa* para o elefante fêmeo, mas não encontrei *elefoa* em nenhum dicionário. Existe *elefoa*? Se não, qual o feminino de *elefante*?

Comment: Não existe elefoa. Seria elefanta ou aliá.

Comment: Bem lembrado @Schilive. Na linguagem informal pode-se escutar.

Answer (score 4):

Sim, existe *elefoa* como feminino informal e etimologicamente errado, ou seja, errado. Os femininos corretos de *elefante* são *elefanta* e *aliá*, que vem do singalês, uma língua do Sri Lanka.

O sufixo -oa só é usado para palavras terminadas em -ão pela sua origem. Antigamente, quando várias palavras que hoje terminam em -ão terminavam em -on (-õ/-õn/-õm), se quisessem tornar essas palavras femininas, punham um -a, então, *leõ* → *leõa* > *leoa* e *leõ* > *leão*, e ainda *varõ* → *varõa* > *varoa* e *varõ* > *varão*. Algumas palavras terminavam em -onus, como *patronus* → *patrona* > *patrõa* > *patroa*. Assim, não faz sentido nenhum *elefante* → *elefoa*, já que *elefante* vem de *elephās*,*antis* ou *elephantus*, por isso é incorreto, mesmo que existente. Contudo, algumas raras palavras que nunca terminaram nem em -onus nem em -on ganharam feminino -oa, como *alemoa* e *capioa*, mas são pejorativos e informais, ou seja, não importa a correção.